# Вставить byte aray в строчку с uri после знака / в гет запросе

Tags: arduino

Пытаюсь вставить byte aray в строчку с uri после знака / в гет запросе
Пока получилось только воткнуть его в заголовки гет запроса,создается 10 заголовков)), было бы здорово вставить его после слэша в строку запроса

Сам скетч:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
OneWire ds(7); // выход считывателя на 7 пин

byte addr[8];// буфер приема
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server(192,168,43,1);// numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 43, 10); //если не сработал dhcp
EthernetClient client;
void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(9600);// стартовая инициализация
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Start...");

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

}

void loop() { 

  if(ds.reset()){// если обнаружено устройство
     String cardId; 
    ds.write(0x33); // отправляем команду "считать ROM"
    delay(50); // на всякий случай ждем
    for(int i=0;i < 8;i++){
      addr[i] = ds.read(); // считываем

    }
    //Serial.print(cardId,HEX);
   // String half = "GET /" + cardId;
      client.connect(server, 8080);
      client.println("GET /addr[i] HTTP/1.1");
      client.println("Host:192.168.43.1:8008");
      client.println("Connection: close");
      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {


   cardId += String((char*)addr[i]);

  }
client.println(cardId);
      client.println();
      client.stop();


  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    Serial.print(addr[i]);
  }

  Serial.println();



    delay(1000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Извините,мой и без того не очень опрятный код тут выглядит еще хуже =/

Answer (score 0):

```
client.connect(server, 8080);
client.print("GET /");
for (int i=0; i<8; ++i)
   client.print((char) addr[i]);
client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host:192.168.43.1:8008");
```

Comment: спасибо,буду пробовать